# how to change ngx-datepicker input format

Tags: angular

I want to get date as input in yyyy-mm-dd and it is showing the same format on selecting date but getting input in 2019-07-08T12:16:10.000Z format.

```
         <input
          class="form-control"
          style="width: 48%;display: inline;margin-left: 17px;"
          bsDatepicker
          placeholder="Month And Year"
          [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }"
          formControlName="month_and_year" >
        </div>
```

I am getting this format `"month_and_year": "2019-07-08T12:16:10.000Z"`.
I want it only in the `"2019-07-08"` format

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the config format like this:

```
  [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }
```

Check the docs [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#format)

**UPDATE**

I think I understand your problem. You created a reactive form like this:

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="myForm">

<input
  class="form-control"
  style="width:48%; display: inline;margin-left: 17px;"
  bsDatepicker
  placeholder="Month And Year"
  [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }"
  formControlName="month_and_year">

</form>
```

And you try to access the field "month_and_year" in your form like this:

```
<pre>myForm: {{ myForm.value | json }}</pre>
```

And you get this:

```
myForm: {
  "month_and_year": "2015-01-30T23:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Now the behavior here is the normal since you are working with Date as a type.
If you have a variable in your component and initialize it with a date something like this:

```
this.today = new Date();
```

then in your html you output it with a json pipe you will get "2019-07-11T08:04:38.221Z":

```
<pre>{{ today | json }}</pre>
```

Similarly if you add a button to update your "month_and_year" like this:

```
<button (click)="setFormDateValue()">Set Form Date Value</button>

  setFormDateValue() {
    this.myForm.patchValue({ month_and_year: new Date(2015, 0, 31) });
  }
```

You are still working with a Date type.

To get only the year, month and day. You have to manually extract it from the form field "month_and_year":

```
<pre>{{ getDateInRequiredFormat(myForm.get("month_and_year").value) }}</pre>
```

The implementation can be something like this:

```
  getDateInRequiredFormat(d: Date): string {
    if (d instanceof Date) {
      let month: string | number = d.getMonth() + 1;
      if (month < 10) {
        month = '0' + month;
      }
      let day: string | number = d.getDate();
      if (day < 10) {
        day = '0' + day;
      }
      return `${d.getFullYear()}-${month}-${day}`;
    }
    return '';
  }
```

After executing this function you will get your selected date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebuntc)

Answer (score 0):

If you use input you can add a date pipe to your value.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" bsDatepicker formControlName="date"  
   [(bsValue)]="newVar" value="{{ newVar | date:'yyyy- MM-dd' }}"/>
```